# docker работа с базой данных

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Вопрос. Как работать с базой данных

Есть вот такой конф.файл - **docker-compose.yml**

**Правильно я понимаю шаги работы**

1. У меня есть sql файл
2. Я копирую его внутрь контейнера lemp_mariadb
3. Там делаю импорт базы и все работает? Нужны ли какие то еще действия

Тогда получается чтобы изменить структуру или данные, то мне всегда нужно будет заходить внутрь контейнера и менять там структуру?

Еще момент

Используется laravel, там есть artisan для миграции.
 Так понимаю что вопрос со структурой будет решен, но как быть с данными, которые могут обновиться?

**Ситуация:** 
Другой разрабочик скачает приложение и ему нужно будет тоже заходить в контейнер и разворачивать базу данных?

```
version: '2'
    services:
      nginx:
        image: evild/alpine-nginx:1.9.15-openssl
        container_name: lemp_nginx
        restart: always
        links:
          - php
        volumes:
          - ./project:/var/www/
          - ./docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
          - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
        ports:
          - 8080:80
          - 443:443
      php:
        image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6
        working_dir: /var/www
        container_name: lemp_php
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./project:/var/www/
        depends_on:
          - db

        links:
          - db
        environment:
          - DB_NAME=mysql
          - DB_USER=root
          - DB_PASSWORD=password
      db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        container_name: lemp_mariadb
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: `Еще момент` – если у вас два вопроса, лучше оформлять их именно как две отдельных публикации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, rule of thumb - структурные изменения (миграции) могут происходить автоматически, все восстановления данных из дампа происходят вручную - просто потому, что эта операция не относится к разряду обычных операций обслуживания. Поэтому дампы действительно стоит заливать вручную в контейнер (можно просто вынести при этом директорию базы данных на хост, чтобы не делать это каждый раз, или создать отдельное dev-изображение с заполненной бд). Заставлять контейнер при запуске вливать дамп и менять его по ходу разработки - не самая лучшая идея.

Большой проблемы в том, что БД будет так или иначе расходиться у разработчиков, я не вижу - это теоретически может порождать пропущенные баги, но при ответственной разработке не должно сильно влиять на происходящие процессы.

Впрочем, в программирование все больше входит такое понятие, как [seed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/seeding) - заполнение базы данных начальными данными, которые гарантированно должны оказаться в этой БД и являются де-факто частью приложения (например, если есть мультирегиональное приложение, которое стартует из Москвы и Питера, есть смысл при первоначальной выкладке приложения создавать эти два региона в БД, чтобы у приложения не было возможности подняться в пустом виде). Это, в отличие от полного восстановления из дампа, является стандартное операцией обслуживания, и в этом случае вы можете создать отдельный seed для разработки, который будет содержать минимальный набор данных, необходимый разработчикам, и полностью автоматизировать данный процесс. В случае с laravel это выглядит наиболее оптимальной стратегией, хотя и потребует больших усилий по поддержке этого набора данных в акутальном состоянии и, скорее всего, потребует пересмотреть систему идентификаторов (отказ о auto increment / serial).

Comment: volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
скажите для чего это строчка? я так понимаю она каким то образом прокидывает данный либо внутрь контейнера либо наоборот

Comment: @ruslik да, все верно, это маунт хост-директории внутрь контейнера - таким образом данные сохранятся между запусками

Comment: я не очень понимаю работу docker, для чего данные сохранять между запусками. Когда я останавливаю контейнер развер данные удаляются?

Comment: я вошел в контейннер, сделал новую запись в базу, остановил контейнер и заново запустил - разве новых данны не будет?

Comment: @ruslik при запуске - будут, при уничтожении - нет. Любое изменение сервиса docker-compose кончается его полным пересозданием, поэтому вероятность потерять данные ненулевая.

Comment: @ruslik а если нужно передать это всё другому разработчкику? Он на своём компьютере создаст контейнер заново из образа. Если в образе эти данные не изменились - он их не увидит. В случае с volume-ом эти данные можно упаковать в tar.gz и передать отдельным файлом с инструкциями, куда подключать. Кроме того, в volume-ах часто внутрь контейнеров передаются всякие ключи и сертификаты. А вот конфиг лучше, чтобы был частью образа - иначе теряем воспроизводимость.

Answer (score 2):

Уже достаточно много копий сломано на stateful-контейнерах. В частности, контейнерах, содержащих БД.

Тут важно определиться с тем, чего мы пытаемся добиться. Варианты такие:

1. Иммутабельное состояние БД. Есть рантайм БД, его конфиги (возможно, использующие переменные окружения при запуске), SQL (DDL) и SQL (DML) с данными на момент старта. С точностью до используемых переменных окружения при каждом запуске мы получаем одно и то же. Можно протестировать, можно быть уверенным, что это будет так у всех разработчиков. Время от времени можно делать SQL-дамп и собирать новую версию контейнера. Минус: при таком подходе мы теряем изменение состояния БД. Хорошо подходит для разработки.
2. Иммутабельная конфигурация и схема. Рантайм БД, конфиги и DDL упакованы в контейнер и верионируются. Данные в виде бинарных рабочих файлов БД (и transaction log-ов) подключаются через volume. Соответственно, не являются иммутабельными. С данными мы работаем отдельно. Бэкапим, обеспечиваем отказоустойчивость. Тут есть опасность: с одним набором файлов данных одновременно может работать только один контейнер без риска их повредить. Другие разработчики, запуская контейнер, должны откуда-то подключить к нему свой набор данных, который будет отличаться от первого. Для разработки это не очень хорошо, но в проде иначе нельзя обеспечить нормальное резервное копирование без потери данных между бэкапами.
3. В отличие от предыдущего варианта, можно данные хранить в отдельном контейнере в виде SQL (DML) и периодически его пересобирать. Подключать к рантайму БД как volume. Опять же, в разработке это позволяет оперировать воспроизводимой конфигурацией БД, включая данные. Но при этом рантайм с конфигурацией и схемой и данные версионируются отдельно. Для воспроизводимости контейнера с данными, он должен собираться каждый раз из SQL (DML)-скрипта. Это может быть удобно: размеры дельт меньше, SQL можно хранить в Git-е, например. Минус в том, что это не всегда возможно. Например, хранить дамп большой БД в Git-е бессмысленно: diff-ы ни о чём не скажут.
4. Вариант в качестве бэкапа коммитить текущее состояние контейнера из прода не рассматривается как Ops Smell. Мы получаем некий бинарник, который непонятно, каким образом получен. Не воспроизводим, хранить много лишнего мусора в виде, например логов. Или просто из-за того, как устроена файловая система Docker-контейнера, которая сохраняет дельты.

Таким образом, пока проект не запущен в прод - первый вариант удобнее. Когда проект уже в проде, как правило возможен только вариант 2. Если же SQL (DML) тщательно делается руками (например, в случае БД с нормативно-справочной информацией), то и в проде можно пользоваться удобствами 3-го варианта.

В конечном счёте, выбор в том, что мы делаем иммутабельным и версионируем, а что делаем ликвидным и "живым", но неверсионируемым.

EDIT: Немного разберёмся в терминологии.

Образ - это то, чем между собой обмениваются разработчики, что отправляется в продакшен; некий застывший слепок, из которого запускается контейнер.

Контейнер - это запущенные процессы, использующие процессор и память, их состояние эфемерно, жизнь в общем случае не стоит ломаного гроша. Запустив два контейнера из одного и того же образа, мы получим одинаковое состояние на старте. Но потом каждый живёт своей жизнью.

Том (volume) - папка из файловой системы хозяина (хоста), которую контейнер воспринимает как часть своей файловой системы. Соответственно, volume переживает рождение, смерть, запуск и остановку контейнеров и хранит всё, что в нём изменилось. Важно, что состояние volume-а отделено от состояния контейнера. Кроме того, работа с volume-ом осуществляется напрямую с файловой системой хоста, минуя прослойку файловой системы контейнера. При интенсивном дисковом IO это даёт выигрыш в производительности. Содержимое volume-а в образе не сохраняется, поэтому не является воспроизводимым (если только это не volume, упакованный в другой образ и контейнер).

Comment: Спасибо за детальное описание! Немногт не хватает, что такое DDL и DML, пошел гугглить..

Comment: @Evgeny DDL - SQL-инструкции для определения данных (таблиц, представлений, триггеров и т.д.). DML - SQL-инструкции для манипуляции данными (select, insert, delete, update)

Comment: спасибо, получается DDL - схема и "C", а DML- "RUD" из CRUD?

Comment: Нет, CRUD относится к данным - это всё DML. "C" - insert. А DDL - про метаданные: create/alter/drop schema/table/trigger/function...